# Was there a change in the charm store?

Tags: juju

Since yesterday we can't deploy juju charms anymore with only specifying the channel. We now have to specify the revision as shown below:

```
user@device:~$ juju info mongodb
name: mongodb
publisher: Canonical Data Platform
summary: A Charmed Operator for MongoDB on Machine
description: |
  Build and run MongoDB with Canonical Charm. This product is a
  MongoDB operator that provides a general-purpose distributed
  document database. In addition, this repository contains a
  Juju Charm for deploying MongoDB on machine clusters.

  Authors
  This Charm is built by Canonical based on source code published
  by MongoDB Inc. This product is not endorsed or published by
  MongoDB, Inc.

  MongoDB and the logo are trademarks, or registered trademarks
  of MongoDB Inc. and other parties may also have trademark
  rights in other terms used herein.
store-url: https://charmhub.io/mongodb
charm-id: Jfd56ZWJ9IaNHuPjXVLP9d9Xa2XMTSKp
supports: jammy
tags: databases
subordinate: false
relations:
  provides:
    cos-agent: cos_agent
    database: mongodb_client
    obsolete: mongodb
  requires:
    certificates: tls-certificates
    s3-credentials: s3
channels: |
  5/stable:       117  2023-04-20  (117)  12MB
  5/candidate:    117  2023-04-20  (117)  12MB
  5/beta:         ↑
  5/edge:         118  2023-05-03  (118)  13MB
  3.6/stable:     100  2023-04-28  (100)  860kB
  3.6/candidate:  100  2023-04-13  (100)  860kB
  3.6/beta:       ↑
  3.6/edge:       100  2023-02-03  (100)  860kB

user@device:~$ juju deploy mongodb --channel 3.6/stable --debug
13:15:56 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:56 running juju [2.9.42 7b871e782195bdac9c90f8a8f01723cc3e08ab92 gc go1.18.10]
13:15:56 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:57   args: []string{"/snap/juju/22345/bin/juju", "deploy", "mongodb", "--channel", "3.6/stable", "--debug"}
13:15:56 INFO  juju.juju api.go:86 connecting to API addresses: [10.56.78.131:17070]
13:15:56 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:1152 successfully dialed "wss://10.56.78.131:17070/api"
13:15:56 INFO  juju.api apiclient.go:687 connection established to "wss://10.56.78.131:17070/api"
13:15:56 INFO  juju.juju api.go:86 connecting to API addresses: [10.56.78.131:17070]
13:15:56 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:1152 successfully dialed "wss://10.56.78.131:17070/model/47324586-91f3-4c88-8bc5-3bb6acecd4f3/api"
13:15:56 INFO  juju.api apiclient.go:687 connection established to "wss://10.56.78.131:17070/model/47324586-91f3-4c88-8bc5-3bb6acecd4f3/api"
13:15:56 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.deployer deployer.go:396 cannot interpret as local charm: file does not exist
13:15:56 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.deployer deployer.go:208 cannot interpret as a redeployment of a local charm from the controller
13:15:56 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
13:15:56 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
ERROR resolving retry error: No revision was found in the Store.
13:15:56 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:537 error stack: 
resolving retry error: No revision was found in the Store.
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/store.(*CharmAdaptor).ResolveCharm:100: 
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/store.(*CharmAdaptor).ResolveBundleURL:135: 
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/deployer.(*factory).maybeReadRepositoryBundle:464: 
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/deployer.(*factory).GetDeployer:71: 
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application.(*DeployCommand).Run:909:

user@device:~$ juju deploy mongodb --revision 100 --channel stable --debug
13:19:07 INFO  juju.cmd supercommand.go:56 running juju [2.9.42 7b871e782195bdac9c90f8a8f01723cc3e08ab92 gc go1.18.10]
13:19:07 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:57   args: []string{"/snap/juju/22345/bin/juju", "deploy", "mongodb", "--revision", "100", "--channel", "stable", "--debug"}
13:19:07 INFO  juju.juju api.go:86 connecting to API addresses: [10.56.78.131:17070]
13:19:07 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:1152 successfully dialed "wss://10.56.78.131:17070/api"
13:19:07 INFO  juju.api apiclient.go:687 connection established to "wss://10.56.78.131:17070/api"
13:19:07 INFO  juju.juju api.go:86 connecting to API addresses: [10.56.78.131:17070]
13:19:07 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:1152 successfully dialed "wss://10.56.78.131:17070/model/47324586-91f3-4c88-8bc5-3bb6acecd4f3/api"
13:19:07 INFO  juju.api apiclient.go:687 connection established to "wss://10.56.78.131:17070/model/47324586-91f3-4c88-8bc5-3bb6acecd4f3/api"
13:19:07 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.deployer deployer.go:396 cannot interpret as local charm: file does not exist
13:19:07 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.deployer deployer.go:208 cannot interpret as a redeployment of a local charm from the controller
13:19:07 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.store charmadapter.go:142 cannot interpret as charmstore bundle:  (series) != "bundle"
13:19:07 INFO  cmd charm.go:452 Preparing to deploy "mongodb" from the charmhub
13:19:09 INFO  cmd charm.go:550 Located charm "mongodb" in charm-hub, revision 100
13:19:09 INFO  cmd charm.go:236 Deploying "mongodb" from charm-hub charm "mongodb", revision 100 in channel stable on focal
13:19:09 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
13:19:09 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
13:19:09 INFO  cmd supercommand.go:544 command finished
```

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** In order to better diagnose your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Also, have any recent changes been made to your machine (e.g., updates/upgrades, installed new applications, etc.)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the charm store was resolved.

```
user@device:~$ juju deploy mongodb --channel 3.6/stable 
Located charm "mongodb" in charm-hub, revision 100
Deploying "mongodb" from charm-hub charm "mongodb", revision 100 in channel 3.6/stable on focal
```